# JavaScript string count loop misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops, variables

I am having trouble with a basic task. I need to write a JavaScript program that contains an array of at least five strings, loops through the array, and calls a function for each item; this function should check to see how long the string is:

- If the string is less than four characters, print the phrase "Less Than Four"
- If equal to four characters, print "Exactly Four"
- If longer than four, print "More Than Four"

I have tried so many things, but feel like I am looking in the wrong spots. I understand this is basic but I cant seem to wrap my head around this...

My Code right now:

```js
var colors = ["teal", "violet", "silver", "green", "red", "purple"];
var count;

for (count = 0; count < colors.length; count++) {
  console.log(colors[count]);
}

if (colors > 4) {
  console.log("greater than 4");
}

if (colors < 4) {
  console.log("less than 4");
}

if (colors = 4) {
  console.log("is equal to 4");
}
```

Comment: You should check each string's [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) property within the `for`-loop. e.g. `console.log(colors[count].length)`.

Comment: You also need to move your `if`s inside the `for` block and use correct comparisons; In the last `if` you're *assigning* instead of *comparing*.

Comment: and = is assignment, == or === is comparison `colors[count].length === 4)` Move the ifs inside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays have built-in methods for looping that allow a callback function to be executed upon each iteration of the loop. In your scenario, since you are just needing to examine the string, the [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method is probably the most appropriate.

In the function, you only need a simple `if/then/else` statement to determine which message to print.

```js
var colors = ["teal", "violet", "silver", "green", "red", "purple"];

colors.forEach(function(color){
  if(color.length < 4){
    console.log(color + " has less than 4 characters.");
  } else if (color.length === 4) {
    console.log(color + " has 4 characters.");  
  } else {
    console.log(color + " has more than 4 characters.");  
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of JavaScript support `for..of` syntax

```js
const colors =
  [ "teal", "violet", "silver", "green", "red", "purple" ]
  
for (const c of colors)
{ if (c.length > 4)
    console.log(c, "greater than 4")
  else if (c.length < 4)
    console.log(c, "less than 4")
  else
    console.log(c, "equal to 4")
}

// teal equal to 4
// violet greater than 4
// silver greater than 4
// green greater than 4
// red less than 4
// purple greater than 4
```

You should separate the concerns of the loop and the length check using a function -

```js
const colors =
  [ "teal", "violet", "silver", "green", "red", "purple" ]
  
const checkLength = str =>
{ if (str.length > 4)
    return "greater than 4"
  else if (str.length < 4)
    return "less than 4"
  else
    return "equal to 4"
}

for (const c of colors)
  console.log(c, checkLength(c))

// teal equal to 4
// violet greater than 4
// silver greater than 4
// green greater than 4
// red less than 4
// purple greater than 4
```

JavaScript is a [multi-paradigm language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm#Support_for_multiple_paradigms), so it supports writing the same program in a wide variety of styles -

```js
const colors =
  [ "teal", "violet", "silver", "green", "red", "purple" ]

const checkLength = str =>
{ if (str.length > 4)
    console.log(`${str} is greater than 4`)
  else if (str.length < 4)
    console.log(`${str} is less than 4`)
  else
    console.log(`${str} is equal to 4`)
}

colors.forEach(checkLength)

// teal equal to 4
// violet greater than 4
// silver greater than 4
// green greater than 4
// red less than 4
// purple greater than 4
```

JavaScript support for expressions is quite good too, removing the need for imperative-style keywords like `if`, `else`, `switch`, `for`, `while`, `do` and even `return` -

```js
const colors =
  [ "teal", "violet", "silver", "green", "red", "purple" ]

const checkLength = x =>
  x.length > 4                   // if ...
    ? `${x} is greater than 4`
: x.length < 4                   // else if ...
    ? `${x} is less than 4`
: `${x} is equal to 4`           // else

console.log(colors.map(checkLength))

// [ "teal is equal to 4"
// , "violet is greater than 4"
// , "silver is greater than 4"
// , "green is greater than 4"
// , "red is less than 4"
// , "purple is greater than 4"
// ]
```

Comment: Please let the very nooby noob learn plain JS first and give them good practices such as bracketed statements

Comment: Wow, ty so much

Comment: @mplungjan I'm reading your comment very carefully and I don't understand it. What does _"learn plain JS first"_ mean? Good practices come _after_? Why not learn good practices first? And what is a _"bracketed statement"_?

Comment: 1. `for (const c of colors) {
  console.log(c, checkLength(c)) }` 2. Learn and understand ECMAScript 5 before switching to ES6 and have to use Babel to support IE, which might be OPs browser of choice. I did not suggest to postpone learning good practices

Comment: You are not fixing OPs homework, you are rewriting it

Comment: @mplungjan  should I learn PHP 5 before learning PHP 7? Should I learn Python 2 before learning Python 3? _"ES6"_ as you call it, is widely supported in many environments. Why do you assume the learner has to deal with IE? What does this have to do with Babel? Are you even sure the learner is running this in a browser? Your concerns show me that maybe it's _you_ that doesn't know how to _"let the very nooby noob learn plain JS..."_

Comment: Let’s agree to disagree. I have been around a few more decennia than you and are fully aware of support for es6. Learn the for loop before the forEach and the function keyword before the arrow function - op is at chapter one and you jump to chapter 20

Comment: @mplungjan being old doesn't make your advice any wiser. You could become a master of programming without ever writing a `for` loop, but the classroom curriculum was built around Basic, C and C++, so imperative style dominates the mind set of the learner. After 15 years of telling the computer what to do, [one book](http://sarabander.github.io/sicp/) showed me everything could be different. The _"you have to start where I started"_ mentality is broken.

Comment: How about “start where you can understand it” I assume you finished some computer degree 5+ years ago, right? Just consider many noobs here never studied computing in a serious manner

Answer (score 0):

Call a function on every element and check the length inside an if-else block

```js
var colors = ["teal", "violet", "silver", "green", "red", "purple"];
var count;

for (count = 0; count < colors.length; count++) {
  console.log(colors[count]);
  stringLength(colors[count]);
}

function stringLength(string) {
  if (string.length > 4) {
    console.log("greater than 4");
  } else if (string.length < 4) {
    console.log("less than 4");
  } else {
    console.log("is equal to 4");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the if statements inside the curly braces of the for loop, so for every color it will run through all the if conditions and print if it matches.

A more idiomatic way of doing what you're currently trying to do is to implement the logic within the body of a forEach function, which is part of the [Array object's prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
var colors = ["teal", "violet", "silver", "green", "red", "purple"];

colors.forEach(function(currentColorToCheck) { //currentColorToCheck is a temporary variable that the forEach function gives you (1 for every item of colors Array)
  if (currentColorToCheck.length > 4) { // we use the .length function (part of String prototype and Array prototype) to get the length of the string
    console.log("greater than 4");
  }

  if (currentColorToCheck.length < 4) {
    console.log("less than 4");
  }

  if (currentColorToCheck.length === 4) { // here for an equality comparison, use === instead of =
    console.log("is equal to 4");
  }
})
```

The forEach is a more convenient way to express "Iterate over values of an Array". You can look at the documentation for some further guidance.

As a sidenote, there's tons of prototype (builtin) functions for every JavaScript type (Object, Array, String, Number, Date, Math, etc.) which you might want to study in your spare time. [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) has great resources for that.

Comment: Why not use  `===` ?

Comment: That is actually recommended, updating the code now.

Comment: With separate `if` statements, each of them will test regardless of how the previous ones resulted. It should be `if/else if/else`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus of course, I tried to stay as true to the original code as possible while still supplying additional information.